# Selected textbox in datagrid is indenting on click

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am working on a user interface issue which is when I click on an item in the grid and it makes the textbox editable, the first byte is indenting so you can see it is selected.

The user does not want this this way, but I have been searching for a solution but I have yet to find it... I already tried to make it non focusable but that makes no difference.

I am using C# WPF, a DataGrid which contains these textboxes.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Can you please post your XAML and any relevant code that shows how your DataGrid is formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself by putting a

```
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2 0 0 0"/>
```